# How to add pagination in joomla custom php code?

Tags: php, mysql, rsform, pagination

Please help me to add pagination ([getLimitBox](https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/Joomla.CMS.Pagination.Pagination.html#method_getLimitBox)) to my table result.
I have for example 100 rows in my table and I want to show 10 page.

```
<?php
$formid=23;
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query
    ->select(array('SubmissionId', 'Username', 'FormId','UserId'))
    ->from('#__rsform_submissions')
    ->where ('FormId='.$formid)
    ->order('Username ASC');
//$query->setLimit('10');
$db->setQuery($query);
$results = $db->loadObjectList();
echo '<table>';
    ?>
    <thead>
        <tr> 
            <th>SubmissionId</th> 
            <th>Username</th> 
            <th>UserId</th> 
            <th>FormId</th> 
        </tr>
    </thead> 
    <?php
        foreach ($results as $row)
        {
            echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td>' . $row->SubmissionId . ' </td>';
                echo '<td>' . $row->Username . ' </td>';
                echo '<td>' . $row->UserId . ' </td>';
                echo '<td>' . $row->FormId . ' </td>';
            echo '</tr>';
        }
echo '</table>';
?>
```

**Update** I changed my code to:

```
<?php
$db = JFactory::getDbo();

$lim    = $mainframe->getUserStateFromRequest("$option.limit", 'limit', 10, 'int'); //I guess getUserStateFromRequest is for session or different reasons
$lim0   = JRequest::getVar('limitstart', 0, '', 'int');

$db->setQuery('SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS SubmissionId, Username, FormId,UserId FROM #__rsform_submissions WHERE FormId=23',$lim0, $lim);
$results = $db->loadObjectList();

$db->setQuery('SELECT FOUND_ROWS();');  //no reloading the query! Just asking for total without limit

$pageNav = new JPagination( $db->loadResult(), $lim0, $lim );

echo '<table>';
    ?>
    <thead>
        <tr> 
            <th>SubmissionId</th> 
            <th>Username</th> 
            <th>UserId</th> 
            <th>FormId</th> 
        </tr>
    </thead> 
    <?php
        foreach ($results as $row)
        {
            echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td>' . $row->SubmissionId . ' </td>';
                echo '<td>' . $row->Username . ' </td>';
                echo '<td>' . $row->UserId . ' </td>';
                echo '<td>' . $row->FormId . ' </td>';
            echo '</tr>';
        }
echo '</table>';
echo $pageNav->getListFooter(  ); //Displays a nice footer

?>
```

It works in **custom module** next is okay.

However, all not show in **front page**.

Article only first list start show when click next it is not show anything.

In **other article** next page displays a **404** error.

Comment: I nearly had a stroke reading the sentence: "Article only first list start show when click next it is not show anything.". I gather the pagination is not showing the next page. Where did you get $mainframe from? It's super old Joomla 1.0 or Mambo code if I remember correctly, and I doubt it works. Same for JRequest::getVar() it's been deprecated for ages, and could very well be responsible for the issue at hand. Replace it with JFactory::getApplication()->input->get('limitstart', 0); but do check the parameters I'm not sure the order is the same

Comment: @RiccardoZorn ok ignore my cods
i want in my  **article** select from one table of data base  that have 100 rows echo table with pagination to display my result in 10 page
i use {source}{/source} plugin to display my cods in article

Answer (score 3):

You have the instruction in your code, but commented.
The query `setLimit()` function requires two parameters:

- `$limit`: the number of records to return, and
- `$offset`: the first record you want to return, zero-based.

This is the signature of the function:

```
public function setLimit($limit = 0, $offset = 0)
```

Please take notice that the parameter order is opposite that of mysql:

```
LIMIT [offset,] row_count;
```

Then you will need to draw some pagination buttons

```
echo "<a href=".JRoute::_("index.php?page=1& ...
```

and so on, and figure out the `$offset` parameter from that. JRoute omitted for clarity.

I should add that you could also code your model extending `ListModel`, and then you'd get pagination for free, courtesy of Joomla. To try and sell this better, consider that all of the above would run down to a call like:

```
echo $this->pagination->getListFooter();
```

You can find some info on [Joomla MVC Docs](https://docs.joomla.org/Model-View-Controller) and sample code on [Joomla component tutorial](https://docs.joomla.org/Part_1:_The_Site_code), but ultimately it would be faster to just read how it's done in the core Joomla components, it's quicker, and you always learn something reading Joomla code.

Comment: are you going to complete that first `echo` or are you purposely leaving it unfinished?

Comment: I like the suspense :-) I added some dots to make it more dramatic

Comment: my article id =15 
i am not professional please write me complete code thank-you

 of my example:(
i use {source}
to php code add to article
@RiccardoZorn

Comment: the purpose of this site is to share knowledge, and help each other; not to do your work! I don't think I could have been more clear, if you developed the code above, it should be well within your skills. If you didn't, show my answer to the developer and they will know what to do

Comment: @RiccardoZorn please see the updated question

Comment: @RiccardoZorn https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14071/joomla