# SQLite Fetch Jump to certain number

Tags: sql

Let's say I have an SQLite Database, and a Table in the said Database has thousands of records, and each record has an article worth thousands of characters within it, it is CMS of course it has an Article within each record, if I want to get 20 records start from 2001st to 2020 then I have to do fetchArray() 2000 times then get 20 records after.
This is what I do

```
$db_CMS = "CMSdatabase.db";
$db = new SQLite3($db_CMS); 
$mydata = $db->query("SELECT * FROM article");

$wastedata = $mydata ->fetchArray(); //do it 2000 times

$needed_data = $mydata ->fetchArray() //get it 20 times
```

The process to get the $wastedata needs 2000 times, which means processing 2000 full-page articles just to be wasted, a full-page article means a lot of chars. can we just skip this 2000 process and just jump to the 2001st record without wasting the 2000 fetchArray() process?

Comment: [How to add pagination in joomla custom php code?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/28823/12352)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the LIMIT and START statements if they are supported in SQLite that allows you to specify which record to 'start' with and 'limit' how many records to retrieve.

In Joomla they would look like this

```
$db->query->start('2001')
$db->query->limit('20')
```

This is a good starting point to understanding how to work with databases in Joomla, https://docs.joomla.org/Accessing_the_database_using_JDatabase

The pagination link posted by @mickmackusa is good reference that is more targeted at what you are trying to do assuming you are wanting to display your records on a Joomla list style page.

Comment: thankyou, I will try first before confirm it